# Get stack trace from Node.js 8 core dump under Alpine 3.6

Tags: node.js, alpine-linux

I have a situation where [`node`](https://github.com/nodejs/node) version 8 crashes when run under Kubernetes in a Docker container based on Alpine 3.6, but not locally. I suspect either some kind of memory corruption or mismatched libraries or something equally strange, since the crash is not reproducible and no logging I have tried has managed to log an issue prior to the crash. I managed to get a core dump generated, but now I cannot find any way to get a stack trace out of the core dump.

- I tried [mdb_v8](https://github.com/joyent/mdb_v8/) but it [does not support Node.js at versions > 6.x](https://github.com/joyent/mdb_v8/issues/65#issuecomment-404246923)
- I tried [llnode](https://github.com/nodejs/llnode) on macOS but that fails with "Architecture or OS not supported"
- Alpine 3.6 does not have an `lldb` package available, so I cannot run `llnode` on it
- Other options, like [`segfault-handler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/segfault-handler) or [`node-report`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-report) also do not work because Alpine 3.6 leaves out the `backtrace` API.

Is there any way I can get a stack trace out of a core dump generated by Node.js version 8 under Alpine 3.6?

Comment: one thing which you can do is create docker image using carbon version, just to check whether its because of your app or OS